# Removing all occurrences of any characters in the word 'dust' in the string

Tags: python, string, split

Example:

```
Input:             Output:
dustbin            bin
```

```
if 'dust' in string:
  new = string.split('dust')
  listToStr = ''.join(map(str, new))
  print(listToStr)
```

The above code works fine.

But if the input changes like this.

```
Input:                       Sample Output:
dustduuuustdustbin            bin
```

The above code doesn't work. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: I still don't see where you're printing anything. `split()` returns a list, not a string.

Comment: Do you want to remove all occurrences of all characters in `dust`, or the exact string `dust`? Your title says one thing; your question says another

Comment: Wait I am editing it again
@barmar

Comment: @barmar Check the question once again  I made it more clear

Comment: You edited the title, the question still says what you said before.

Comment: Just so we're clear, if the input is `abcde` the result should be `abce`? It doesn't have all the letters in `dust`, just one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regular expression.

```
import re

result = re.sub(r'[dust]', '', string)
```

The regexp `[dust]` matches any of those characters, and all the matches are replaced with an empty string.

If you want to remove only the whole word `dust`, with possible repetitions of the letters, the regexp would be `r'd+u+s+t+'`.

If only `u` can be repeated, use `r'du+st'`.

Comment: This works but if the input is ```playeddustdustusst``` It will return ```playe```

Comment: That's right. the `d` in `played` is one of the characters in `dust`. You said they should all be removed.

Comment: How is it supposed to know that some d's should be kept and others should be removed? If you can't explain the criteria, you can't program it.

Comment: I've updated the answer with some more possibilities. But the question isn't very clear, so it shouldn't be upvoted.

Answer (score -1):

Use the below function definition, to remove any pattern from any string.
***re*** allows to remove the match with the **pattern** allowing to print only the **non-matched** string.

```
import re
def remover(input, pattern):
  temp='['
  temp+=pattern
  temp+=']'
  return re.sub(r''+temp,'',input)
remover("dustttttttttbinggg",'dust')
```